# Google Cloud Node.js Socket Server Application Hosting

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, ssl, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have two node js application. One of them is a webserver. It serves static html css javascript and image files. This web server is running on google cloud app engine. I have a domain that is bind to this app engine. And whenever a user visits my domain my webserver gives responses to it and it gets my frontend of my website.

The other node application is a socket server(socket io). It runs on a compute engine and i want this socket server to communicate securely. Because there are important messages for me in a communication of client and server sockets. Thats why i bought an ssl certificate.

I applied my ssl certificate to my domain and now i want my client sockets to connect to a port of my domain(for example to `https://www.example.com:8443`)

However i dont know how to forward 8443 port of my domain into my compute engine's 8443 port without terminating the https security.

How can i do that?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Well the Google Console has a networking section from where you can open ports for your applications. See this link: https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/list?project={your-project-id}. Replace {your-project-id} with your project id.

Another option is that instead of using a ssl certificate, you can encrypt the messages sent between your server and client